# Disable horizontal scroll bar in QWebView Qt5

Tags: c++, css, qt5, qdialog, qtwebview

I'm having a problem with the scroll bar in Qt5.4. Right now, I'm trying to display a webpage in a Qt Application, and I do this by adding a Qwebview widget inside a Qdialog, everything works fine, except that I would like to disable the horizontal scroll bar in the Qdialog. A picture is attached below.[image]

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

this issue happened because of width of a html element.
one of the html element (image, div,...) width are more than the width of dialog you declared. the html elements can not be scaled automatically!
you can set css to overflow:hidden for the body of the html or the second way is to set wider width for the dialog.